# Sprite Kit collision happens several points outside the sprite

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a bunch of SKSpriteNode's set up. My hero's node isn't supposed to run into walls and if it does, it will trigger a collision. That works fine but the collision point isn't exactly on the sprite's image.

Here is the hero's code:

```
hero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"hero"];
hero.name = heroCategoryName;
hero.position = CGPointMake(100, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:hero.frame.size.width];
hero.physicsBody.friction = 1.0f;
hero.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0f;
hero.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.1f;
hero.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
hero.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = heroCategory;
hero.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory;
hero.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
hero.physicsBody.mass = 0.2f;
[self addChild:hero];
```

Here are the walls:

```
SKSpriteNode *wall  = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"wall"];
        wall.name = wallCategoryName;
        wall.hidden = YES;

        wall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:wall.size];
        wall.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        wall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
        wall.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        wall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;
        wall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = heroCategory;
```

This happens no matter if the collision is on top, left or right. I've gone and made sure that my images were all crapped as much as they can be. I'm not sure what else it could be. It just seems like the hitbox for the body is bigger than it should be.

Comment: I see this all the time *in the simulator*. It was driving me nuts. I finally tried a real device and the collisions were suddenly perfect! Are you using a device or simulator?

Comment: You don't seem to have your collision bit masks set up... If you set up the hero's collision bitmask to that of the wall, the hero's sprite will be automatically configured to not pass through it.

Comment: I'll try it on a real device tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the dimensions of the hero sprite?  If it's a square image, then change the following

```
hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:hero.frame.size.width];
```

into

```
hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:hero.frame.size.width/2.0f];
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would divide by 2? The image is just a test image right now - 60x68.

Comment: See the documentation about bodyWithCircleOfRadius.  The body's origin lies at the center. 'r' is the radius of the circle.